# getting Fatal error in prestashop 1.6

Tags: php, prestashop-1.6

I am getting Fatal error: Call to undefined method Tools::getSellerPath() in prestashop 1.6. The debug mode is off. Anyone please help me. I am new in prestashop.

Answer (score 1):

The `Tools` class doesn't have a `getSellerPath` method. Probably some third party module tries to call it. Find the module that is causing the problem and either disable or modify it.